# Making your own cusctom workflow developed in visual studio 2010 available in sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Well my requirement is :

Need to develop a custom workflow,the workflow should take properties like site url, list names etc., From the client.

I am able to develop the workflow, but i need to make it available in designer. I tried the method mentioned here:

http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/03/13/make-a-custom-activity-available-to-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx.

1)I have created the required action file.
2)deployed(copy-pasted) dll into gac.
3)made safe-control and authorized type entries in web.config of the corresponding web application(on which my site collection exists)

But it is not helping me out.after following the steps given,when i try to open any workflow in designer,it gives an error saying it cannot find an action(assembly) with xyz name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you built an entire workflow and am trying to make it available to SharePoint Designer.  The guide you are following deals with custom "Actions".  Actions are a sub part of a workflow.  This may explain why your deployment isn't working, because you're trying to deploy a workflow as an action.
If you could provide more information about your steps, we could try and figure it out.

Thanks

### C

http://www.cjvandyk.com/blog